# Manually delete file in application on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Is there a command to directly delete files in Heroku?

I have a `.dat` file in the root directory of an app in Heroku, but it has seeded development data that it should not have.

The application already has a rake task I can use to recreate the file. But first it needs to be deleted or this command will only open it.

`File.open("file_name.dat", "wb") { //do sth }`

My thought is to push a new rake task with `File.delete("file_name.dat")` to wipe it out, but that seems excessive if a command for this purpose already exists.

Is there a way to delete a file directly?

Comment: Can't you just redeploy the app after removing the file or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope unfortunately you'll need to push the change via a new full release.